# Can I apply MERGE INTO on PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, merge, datatable, databricks

I have two PySpark DataFrames and I want to merge these DataFrames. When I try to use MERGE INTO statement, I get an error that there is no table. I am running the code in Databricks.

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

target_data = {'id': [1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500],
              'name': ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person5"],
              'location': ["Location1", "Location2", "Location3", None, "Location5"],
              'contact': [None, "Contact2", None, "Contact4", None],
               }

pdf = pd.DataFrame(target_data)
target = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)


source_data = {'id': [1400, 1500, 1600],
              'name': ["Person4", "Person5", "Person6"],
              'location': ["Location4", "Location5", "Location6"],
              'contact': ["Contact4", "Contact5", "Contact6"],
               }

pdf = pd.DataFrame(source_data)
source = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

And using SQL statement in the next cell:

```
%sql

MERGE INTO target as t
USING source as s
ON t.id = s.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT *
```

I get the error:

[image]

Is there any way that I can merge two DataFrames? Should I convert them into Delta table first?

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895469/2986344) and if you are looking to drop duplicates as well you can leverage `dropDuplicates` function.

```
>>> output_df=source.union(target).dropDuplicates(["id"])
>>> output_df.orderBy(["id"]).show()
+----+-------+---------+--------+
|  id|   name| location| contact|
+----+-------+---------+--------+
|1100|Person1|Location1|    null|
|1200|Person2|Location2|Contact2|
|1300|Person3|Location3|    null|
|1400|Person4|Location4|Contact4|
|1500|Person5|Location5|Contact5|
|1600|Person6|Location6|Contact6|
+----+-------+---------+--------+
```

Output:

Comment: `here` link is coming to the same post. :)

Comment: @Frosty the other answers was actually removed.

Comment: @teedak8s Thanks for your help. How to be sure that the newest records remain in the output DataFrame after dropping duplicates?